# PHPStorm считает подсвечивает валидный синтаксис как не валидный

Tags: typescript, phpstorm

Использую TypeScript 3.9.5, PHPStorm ругается на такой синтаксис экспорта

[image]

Comment: Если там не настраивается, то жди пока выйдет обновление.

Comment: import, а не export

Answer (score 0):

Надо обновиться до последней версии PHPStorm 2020.1.2